# How to get GitHub Actions workflow summary?

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I need to get a workflow summary (i.e. the info I published using `$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY`) for specific `RUN_ID` in my workflow.
I reviewed https://docs.github.com/en/rest, https://github.com/actions/github-script, GH CLI manual - but I still don't understand how to fetch this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to these job summaries is a bit convoluted...

First call the REST API for the runs of a job:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/{runid}/jobs
```

This will return a json payload:

```
{
  "total_count": 1,
  "jobs": [
    {
      "id": 13143160145,
      "run_id": 4850518271,
      "workflow_name": "test",
      "head_branch": "main",
      "run_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/4850518271",
      "run_attempt": 1,
      "node_id": "CR_kwDOJV3v7c8AAAADD2S1UQ",
      "head_sha": "db07f0a8a0eb2104583a4165c86d4da5603c8944",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/jobs/13143160145",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/4850518271/jobs/8643488313",
      "status": "completed",
      "conclusion": "success",
      "created_at": "2023-05-01T10:40:11Z",
      "started_at": "2023-05-01T10:40:18Z",
      "completed_at": "2023-05-01T10:40:20Z",
      "name": "build",
      "steps": [
...
```

Now grab the `html_url` and take that last ID off of it: `https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/4850518271/jobs/**8643488313**`

and use that to fetch the `summary_raw`:

`https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/4850518271/jobs/8643488313/summary_raw`

Which should return the raw markdown for the job summary.

I'm not 100% sure what that ID signifies as I can't find a reference to it elsewhere in the docs.

Comment: I was searching along the lines and that ID does look something cryptic. Could not get it with GitHub CLI. Only thing closer to this I got is with `gh run view --log | grep GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` but then it needs some clean up. It could have been much simpler as the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-job-summary) say that it's uploaded somewhere. A direct link would have been much easier to use.

Comment: I suspect there is a direct link somewhere, but you'd need the right url to find it I haven't found what this ID stands for.

Comment: @jessehouwing - many thanks!
>I suspect there is a direct link somewhere, but you'd need the right url to find it I haven't found what this ID stands for.

In my case workflow has a few jobs, so the most straightforward solution  (but missing) should provide summary for workflow, not per job.

Comment: Not sure if this is outdated, but the html_url for me is equivalent to: `https://github.com/owner/repo/actions/runs/6122437571/job/16618189294`. It is *job, not *jobs, which doesn't work when attempting to fetch the summary